# css media query won't have effect in if condition. why is it so?

Tags: html, css

```
<?php 
    if(isset($rowa['title'])) {
        echo 'style="@media (min-width: 768px) {grid-area: 4 / 2 / span 1 / span 1}  "';
    } 
?>
```

when I remove `@media (min-width)` the code is executed successfully

Comment: Yes this does. How can I solve the problem the other way?.

Comment: That is also explained in that duplicate already - create a `<style>` element instead, and create a rule with a selector that applies to your target element inside of that.

Comment: I'd define a class (in your CSS file, or in a style element in the HTML) which exists within a media query, and then just give your element that class.